# zap-api-scan.py fails to scan api paths in JSON file

Tags: docker, owasp, zap

I’m trying to get `zap-api-scan.py` to scan the API paths in our JSON file. The command I use is as follows:

```
'docker run -v /tmp/zap_scan.conf:/zap/wrk/zap_scan.conf:rw -v /tmp/api_security_html_report.html:/zap/wrk/api_security_html_report.html:rw --name {} zap-api-scan.py -t {} -c zap_scan.conf  -f openapi -r api_security_html_report.html -a -d -j'.format(zap2docker_docker_url, json_url)   

zap2docker_docker_url = "zap2docker dockerhub.xxx.com/isepy-release-docker/owasp_zap2docker-live:latest"
```

Same happens with `docker/owasp_zap2docker-stable:latest`

```
json_file = "https://10.0.10.130/api/v2/api-docs?group=123"  (in OpenApi JSON format)
```

What I see in the zap run output is the URL: https://10.0.10.130/api/v2/api-docs?group=123 and other is not related URLs that look like http://zap/JSON/core/view/alerts/?baseurl=https://10.0.10.130/&start=0&count=5000

However, I do not see any API paths (URLs) from our actual JSON file which are scanned, which are the URLs we wanted to use `zap-api-scan.py` tool for. Note that the “-d” we added the docker command got us this level of verbosity.

Could you please advise if we might be doing something wrong or how do we get zap to pick up the URL in our JSON file?

In addition, does Zap have a docker image with a Wireshark on it which we can troubleshoot this with  (see if any pcap contains our URLs scanned and the “-d” verbosity just fails to report them).

Thanks.

Comment: Is the json file an actual OpenAPI defnition or just some random json format you've put together? (ZAP expects OpenAPI)

Comment: Also why are you trying to map specific files with -v why not just mount /tmp as /zap/wrk ? isepy-release-docker/owasp_zap2docker-live:latest does not seem to be an official zaproxy image so who knows what's right or wrong with it. I'd suggest your review info here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/

Comment: As kingthorin said. Also its easier to debug things using the ZAP desktop :)

Comment: kingthorin, its an OpenApi JSON, not some random format. this happens both with owasp_zap2docker-live:latest and with owasp_zap2docker-stable:latest, we used the docker-live to be able to have the beta alerts. The change of mapping has no effect on the result.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Regarding ZAP desktop, we do wanna be able to perform an automated api path python scan based on the OpenApi json and not by attaching it directly to our repo and performing the desktop scan (https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/api-scan/) Is there anything else that might explain why we don't see our api paths being scanned as all the "rejects" you mentioned are not the ones that seem to cause this.